# Laurent Series for $\frac{z}{(z+2)(z+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I need to find a Laurent series of $ f(z) = \frac{z}{(z+2)(z+1)}$  centered at $z_0 = -2$

The partial fractions of $f$ is $ \frac{2}{(z+2)} - \frac{1}{(z+1)} $

Now, $\frac{1}{(z+1)} = \frac{1}{(z+2)-1} =  \frac{-1}{1 -(z+2)} = - \frac{1}{1 -(z+2)} = - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (z+2)^n $.

So we have the Laurent Series $ \frac{2}{(z+2)} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (z+2)^n $ centered at $z_0 = -2$. The function has a pole of order 1.

Its my resolution correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct. WolframAlpha confirms this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B2%2Cz%2B2%5D%2BSum%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29z%2B2%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2Cinf%7D%5D

Comment: @phi-rate Thanks